# JQuery UI Autocomplete not working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am really confuse why my autocomplete is not working. Can you please help my why this is not working. Even the Date Time picker is not working , I am wondering if is it the template that I am using "Gentellela Alela". Please help my guys. Thanks in advance

Below are the codes

```
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/cust.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>



   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%= txtProdCode.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<%:Page.ResolveUrl("~/WS/Platts.asmx/FilterItem")%>",
                        data: "{ 'filterstring': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.prDesc,
                                    value: item.prDesc
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2

            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

Windows Service (.asmx)

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function FilterItem(ByVal filterstring As String) As List(Of ProductDetail)
        Dim retEmp As New List(Of ProductDetail)
        Using secrpt As New BLL.TradingModel.TradingTransactionRepository
            retEmp = secrpt.GetAllPlattCode().Where(Function(c) c.prDesc.ToLower.Contains(filterstring)).ToList
        End Using
        Return retEmp
    End Function
```

---

Repository

```
Public Function GetAllPlattCode() As List(Of ProductDetail)
            Return (From _plt As ProductDetail In TradingTransactionCTX.ProductDetails Order By _plt.pID).ToList
        End Function
```

Comment: Is there any masterpage ?

Comment: @SaadSuri yes there is a master page

Comment: Then try to call your textbox with master name. you can find it through inspect element.

Comment: That works in my case 
Portfoliotxt_services.ClientID

Comment: @SaadSuri in my code it is txtProdCode.ClientID same as yours

Comment: I concatenate my MasterPage name with text id which you can find it through inspect element

Comment: @SaadSuri SitetxtProdCode.ClientID it is in blue line???

Comment: $("#<%= txtProdCode.ClientID%>") here

Comment: @SaadSuri yes same as yours I am wondering why is still not working :(

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
   <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
```

and then you can use any jquery element or commands.

Comment: you always have to add the jquery.js before you can use any other jquery command or widget.